# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
/*formularen er ikke blevet postet endnu, vis den.
bemÃ¦rke, at action = "" vil medfÃ¸re, at formularen til at sende til den samme side det er pÃ¥ */
echo '<form method="post" action="">
<table border="0" >
 <tr><td>   Dit navn: </td><td> <input type="text" class="ed" name="bruger_navn" />
<tr><td>    Din adresse: </td><td>  <input type="text" class="ed" name="bruger_adresse" />
<tr><td>    Din email: </td><td> <input type="email"  class="ed" name="bruger_email" />
<tr><td>    VÃ¦lg password: </td><td>   <input type="password"  class="ed" name="bruger_kode"/>
<tr><td>    BekrÃ¦ft password: </td><td>  <input type="password"  class="ed" name="bruger_kode_check"/>

<br> <tr><td>

        <div class="check">
        <label for="checkbox">Jeg har lÃ¦st og er acceptere  centrets regler</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="check" required />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="button1" />
 </form></td><td>';


}
else
{
/* Formularen er blevet postet. Dataen bliver behandlet i tre trin:
    1.  Tjek dataen
    2.  Lad brugeren udfylde de tomme felter, hvis det er nÃ¸dvendigt
    3.  Gem dataen 
*/
$errors = array(); /* erklÃ¦re arrayet til senere brug */

if(isset($_POST['bruger_navn']))
{
    //Brugernavnet findes ctype_alnum  betyder at den skal indholder kun tal og bogstaver "Ingen Mellemrum".        
    if(!ctype_alnum($_POST['bruger_navn']))
    {
        $errors[] = 'Brugernavnet kan kun indeholde bogstaver og tal.';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['bruger_navn']) > 30)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Brugernavnet mÃ¥ ikke vÃ¦re lÃ¦ngere end 30 tegn.';
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'Du skal udfylde et brugernavn.';
}


if(isset($_POST['bruger_kode']))
{
    if($_POST['bruger_kode'] != $_POST['bruger_kode_check'])
    {
        $errors[] = 'Adgangskoden matcher ikke.';
    }
}
else
{
    $errors[] = 'Du skal udfylde en adgangskode.';
}

if(!empty($errors)) /*kontrollere, om der er et tomt array, hvis der er fejl, hvis der er, er de i dette array*/
{
    echo 'Du mangler at udfylde nogle felter.<br /><br />';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* gÃ¥r gennem arrayet, sÃ¥ alle fejl bliver vist */
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* Her laves en liste med fejlene */
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
else
{
    // formularen er nu postet uden fejl, sÃ¥ det bliver gemt
    // bemÃ¦rk brug af mysql_real_escape_string, holder alt sikkert!
    // SHA1 funktionen, hasher adgangskoden
    $sql = "INSERT INTO
                bruger(bruger_navn, bruger_adresse, bruger_email, bruger_kode, fk_roller_id)
            VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_navn']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_email']) . "',
                   '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_adresse']) . "',

                                    '" . sha1($_POST['bruger_kode']) . "',


                    NOW(),
                    1)";
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: You are trying to insert 6 items and you specified only 5 columns

Comment: english will get you more answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a 5 fields in your query and you insert 6 values into it.

```
 INSERT INTO
            bruger(bruger_navn, bruger_adresse, bruger_email, bruger_kode, fk_roller_id)
        VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_navn']) . "',
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_adresse']) . "',
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bruger_email']) . "',

                                '" . sha1($_POST['bruger_kode']) . "',
                1)
```

so remove unused value.(according to me you have a no field of time so i remove `now()` from your query)   or if you have a time related field into database then add into your query.

note: i adjust the order of your values.

Comment: Moreover, he exchanged email & address in values given the order of his columns

Comment: ya..true..i update the answer.